# Objective-C Serial - Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, arduino

I'm currently running the followin in Terminal to send a command over USB serial.

```
/Users/drummerboyx/Library/Scripts/arduino-serial -b 9600 -p /dev/tty.usbserial-A800ev0Z -s 1
```

Is there a way to do this in Objective-C?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some google-fu found:

- [Serial Communication Cocoa Framework](http://www.arduino.cc/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1221138443) (on arduino.cc!)
- [AMSerialPort](http://www.harmless.de/cocoa-code.php#serialport)

I know pretty much nothing about it, but the name ["IOKit"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html) also sounds pretty promising...

Answer (score 21):

[ORSSerialPort](http://blog.andrewmadsen.com/post/26512371699/orsserialport-a-new-objective-c-serial-port-library) is a newer, easier to use alternative to AMSerialPort.

Using ORSSerialPort to open a port and send data can be as simple as this:

```
ORSSerialPort *serialPort = [ORSSerialPort serialPortWithPath:@"/dev/cu.KeySerial1"];
serialPort.baudRate = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:4800];
[serialPort open];
[serialPort sendData:someData]; // someData is an NSData object
[serialPort close];
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this looks like a much cleaner library!

Comment: You made an typo with `serialPortWithPath:`, you said `serialPortWithWithPath:`, you added an extra with in the method name.

Comment: Note: If you want to support PowerPC based Macs, you (unfortunately) can't use ORSSerialPort.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to run that command from your code, you can use the [system](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/system/) function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

system("/Users/drummerboyx/Library/Scripts/arduino-serial -b 9600 -p /dev/tty.usbserial-A800ev0Z -s 1");
```

You'll need to set your Objective-C source code file extension to .mm, which tells Xcode to compile it as Objective-C++.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to Cocoa - Have a look at [NSTask](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to do this WITHOUT running system commands?