# Read data from serial port using thread

Tags: cocoa, serial-port, applescript-objc

At first - sorry for my english

I need to read data from serial port (from GPS reciever)
I wrote a small app using SerialPort X2. It works.
But. I read data every 1 sec (on timer fire). And the recieving data is not very well. it could be without some first bytes or last bytes. So I need to read data from the "thread" (I did it when I wrote using Delphi in Windows).
I know that it could be using ObjC, but I am quit newbie in C

If someone have a small example (with tons of comments) on how to do it - it will be very helpfull

thanks

xCode 4,  MacOSX 10.6

Comment: When you wrote "serial port", do you mean a "universial serial port" (USB)?  I mean, it wouldn't be another kind of serial port such as  RS-232 because I don't think that those are used anymore.  So you mean a USB port.  Right?

Comment: No, USB isn't a port - it is a BUS. And there's a big different - port vs bus. I mean exactly serial port like RS-232, and most of GPS recievers use RS-232 protocol. It connects thru USB, but using RS232 to USB adapter.

Comment: OK.  I understand better now.

Comment: I googled and found the following link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153818/objective-c-serial-mac-os-x

Comment: I'll try to understand this and import to my applescriptobjc app. Thank you